# how to use jquery in my content pages?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

net c# web application and page that using master page
i used jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js for  textbox it's not working in content place holder 
but it's working in page without master page

maserpage

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="QcPipe_webAp.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>


<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

content

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="QcPipe_webAp.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#TextBox1').timepicker();

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').timepicker({

});
```

[`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) of the control - is the real unique ID for the control generated during the page render.